# One GET request not working but others work

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I copy/pasted almost everything from my other GET request which works but the "/creation/add" one doesn't and I have no idea why.

I tried many things like removing the content of the GET method and just testing a console print but that didn't work either. I also tried switching it to a POST method and got the same results. There's a POST method just called "/creation" so I thought maybe it's the "/add" that's causing a problem but even switching the name to something different doesn't work.

**app.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('Server address: http://localhost:3000')
    });

    app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
    app.use('/style', express.static(__dirname + '/style'));
    app.use('/views/pages', express.static(__dirname + '/views/pages'));
    app.use('/views/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/views/partials'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/creation/add'), function (req, res) {
    var question = req.query.questions;
    var reponse = req.query.reponses;
    var query = "INSERT INTO `" + selectedCour + "` VALUES (NULL, `" + question + "`, `" + reponse + "` CURDATE())";

    if (!/^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/.test(question) && !/^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/.test(reponse)) {
        connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
            if (!err) {
                currentExamJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
            }
        });
    }
    res.render('pages/creationExam', {data: currentExamJson});
};
```

**html form**

```
<div class="add-container">
            <div style="height:100%;width:100%;float: right;">
                <form class="form-addQ" method="get" action="/creation/add">
                    <input type="text" required="" name="questions" class="text-linex"
                           placeholder="question">
                    <input type="text" required="" name="responses" class="text-linex"
                           placeholder="response">
                    <button id="btnAddQ" style="margin-top: 12px;" class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">add
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing route handler in app.get.

```
   app.get('/creation/add',
        function (req, res) {
            var question = req.query.questions;
            var reponse = req.query.reponses;
            var query = "INSERT INTO `" + selectedCour + "` VALUES (NULL, `" + question + "`, `" + reponse + "` CURDATE())";

            if (!/^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/.test(question) && !/^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/.test(reponse)) {
                connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
                    if (!err) {
                        currentExamJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
                    }
                });
            }
            res.render('pages/creationExam', {
                data: currentExamJson
            });
        });
```